# VBA module for Access painfully slow

Tags: ms-access, vba

Doing data analysis for a lab and I have a table of samples that failed and all the criteria they could've failed on. Trying to add a field with a string listing which criteria each sample failed on.

I just learned VBA 2 weeks ago so I don't really know what I'm doing. I used recordset to turn my table into an array, then looped through each record to see if each criteria has failed and add it to a new failure array if it has. Then I print the failure array in an ugly concatenated string. There are less than 100 records but it's still very slow and sometimes crashes Access. Here's my code:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Dim arrFails() As Variant
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim HType As Integer
Dim S As Integer

Public Sub MakeArrs()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Set db = CurrentDb
     'Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("S" & HType & "RptSimple")

    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("S31RptSimple")

    rs.MoveLast
    rs.MoveFirst
    S = rs.RecordCount - 1
    Debug.Print S
    Dim arrRpt() As Variant
    arrRpt = rs.GetRows(S + 1)
    Debug.Print arrRpt(0, 0)
    'This line creates an array arrFails with sample runs as rows, and 9 columns. Each column is a failure criteria.
    ReDim arrFails(0 To S, 0 To 8) As Variant


    Dim i As Long
    Let i = 0
    Dim index As Long
    'This For loop starts at the first record in arrRpt and goes across the row with an If loop for each of the failure criteria.
    'If the sample failed for that criteria, it populates the new arrFails array with the name of the criteria.
    'If the sample passed, that spot on the array stays null.
    'At the end of one loop, we have a row that ONLY has values for the criteria that failed.
    For index = 0 To S
        If arrRpt(2, i) < 0.85 Or IsNull(arrRpt(2, i)) = True Then
        arrFails(i, 0) = "Correlation, "
        End If
        If arrRpt(3, i) > -0.4 Or arrRpt(3, i) < -2 Or IsNull(arrRpt(3, i)) = True Then
        arrFails(i, 1) = "Slope, "
        End If
        If arrRpt(4, i) < 0.5 Or arrRpt(4, i) > 100 Or IsNull(arrRpt(4, i)) = True Then
        arrFails(i, 2) = "Slope_Ratio, "
        End If
        If arrRpt(5, i) < 2 Or IsNull(arrRpt(5, i)) = True Then
        arrFails(i, 3) = "Valid_Points, "
        End If
        If IsNull(arrRpt(6, i)) = False Then
        arrFails(i, 4) = "Fail_Code, "
        End If
        If arrRpt(7, i) < 1.5 Or arrRpt(7, i) > 10 Or IsNull(arrRpt(7, i)) = True Then
        arrFails(i, 5) = "DilutionRatio1, "
        End If
        If arrRpt(8, i) < 1.5 Or arrRpt(8, i) > 10 Or IsNull(arrRpt(8, i)) = True Then
        arrFails(i, 6) = "DilutionRatio2, "
        End If
        arrFails(i, 8) = arrRpt(0, i)
        i = i + 1

    Next

    rs.Close

    'This is error handling code, so if something goes wrong it'll gracefully exit the code instead of getting some poor user stuck in debug hell.
ExitSub:
        Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
        MsgBox "There's been an error."
        Resume ExitSub
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

End Sub

Public Function FailList2(HPVType, UIDFieldname)
    HType = HPVType
    Call MakeArrs
    Dim x As Variant
    x = 0
    Do While x < S + 1
    If UIDFieldname = arrFails(x, 8) Then
    FailList2 = arrFails(x, 1) & arrFails(x, 0) & arrFails(x, 2) & arrFails(x, 3) & arrFails(x, 4) & arrFails(x, 5) & arrFails(x, 6)
    Exit Do
    End If
    x = x + 1
    Loop
End Function
```

Help a newbie out? There must be a more efficient way to do this. I tried turning echo off until the end of the FailList2 function but it didn't help. Note that I need to keep 'Htype' in the function. I'm just running this on one table right now, but when I fix it I have 8 more tables to run it on, hence the rs code I commented out at the beginning.

Comment: Curious. How long (seconds) is "very slow"? Basically you are doing a single loop over < 100 items. This should be instantaneous. -- Why do you have separate variables `i` and `index`? -- I doubt you gain anything by using `rs.GetRows` instead of a `Do While Not rs.EOF` loop. Maybe it's even the culprit.

Comment: And: How many columns has `S31RptSimple`? What data types are they? -- You can add some `Debug.Print Timer` statements in the code, to find out where exactly it is slow. Or `Start = Timer  ...  Debug.Print Timer-Start`

Comment: @HansUp Here http://imgur.com/Szycbj3 is a screenshot with the original table on the bottom and the desired output on the top. I had to remove part of the SampleID because privacy, but you get the idea. Most of the code is just checking the values against the fail criteria, which is why it might seem arbitrary.  I and index are two separate variables because I derped, and I never thought to use a Do While Not EOF loop! I'll give that a shot now, thanks.

Comment: @Andre451 It's 5 to 7 seconds, but it's 5 to 7 seconds every time I scroll or click on something. This table is actually 47 records, it's the other tables that might go up to 100. S31RptSimple has 9 columns, mostly Single with one short text and one long integer. I'll try the debug.print Timer if swapping to a Do While Not EOF loop doesn't fix the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Running the loop is a split second only, so "5-7 second every time I scroll or click on something" indicates that something else is going on - like calling this at the OnCurrent event. You leave us guessing.

Comment: @Gustav I'm not calling the sub directly in any events, just using it as it's called through the FailList2 function. I have that function as a field in a query. Could that be the problem, and if so how would I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have that function as a field in a query

Uh-oh. There is the problem. Just open the Immediate window, open your query and watch the Debug.Print statements roll in. The function will be executed over and over again.

You need to execute the function **once**, write the results not into an array (arrFails), but into a table instead. Use `Recordset.AddNew` to add records.

Then use that table as input for your query.

Comment: Well, as said: "something else is going on".